# copy milion record from oracle to another oracle

Tags: oracle

i have to "copy" 30 milions of record form a table of Oracle12C to the same in another Oracle12C istance (placed on another server, on another subnet, no way to connect both at same time ) via select statement, like:

```
SELECT * ENVELOPE WHERE ENVELOPE.SUB_DELIVERY_DATE < :dateMax AND ENVELOPE.FLAG_EXTRACTED = 'S'
```

googling and serching here on s.o. I read somthing about *exp* or *expdp* Oracle tools, but i don't want to export all table ( schema, indexs, constraint ), just data.

Can someone help me solve this problem, or show me an alternative solution? thank you so much

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to create a database link between the two databases and pipe the data across that way. If you can't do that, write a PL/SQL procedure to export your data from your source database as a CSV, then copy the file from source machine to target machine, then write another procedure to read the CSV and insert the data into your target database.

Comment: @BobJarvis unfortunately I can not directly connect the two db and I can not write programs or custom procedures of any kind. I can only use existing tools, better if supplied directly with the DB

Comment: just an idea, can you copy those 30 millions data into a table(or few tables depends on your requirements ) then you export these specific table  into another server? I know you said you dont want export tall tables .. well in my idea put all the data in one table.

Comment: You can use expdp with the DATA_ONLY option.  See usage here -https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g